# Cartridge wheel bearings - is there an inside/outside?

Tags: maintenance

I'm replacing the bearings in a standard single speed wheel. I've got 6000-series bearings and I can't find info on whether there is an inside/outside.

Comment: Some bearings I was working with recently did not have an obvious inside/outside, but I recall working with some about 20 years back that did.

Comment: From working with rollerblade bearings (r608zz) there is no inside or outside.   However if one side looks more damaged, face that inwards for weather/water protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little Googling I found http://www.gizmology.net/bearings.htm

To summarize, the four digits each have a meaning

- If the first digit is a number it is a metric bearing (the alternative is R, for inches. I didn't find out why R is for inches or if there are other first "digits").
- First digit 6: Single-Row Deep Groove Ball Bearing
  Typical ball bearing. Handles light axial loads as well as radial loads.
  Type 6, "single-row deep groove", is perhaps the most common type of bearing.
- Second digit 0: Extra light duty
- Third and fourth digits 00: 10mm

The article explains many details not relevant to this case.

So, being a *single-row deep groove* bearing, it doesn't have an intrinsic orientation. If it had a cover fitted to one side then that would be the outside.

Answer (score 3):

Among bike parts manufacturers, the norm by a very wide margin is for there not be sidedness. There are exceptions, such as hubs that use sealed cartridge angular contact bearings, but I believe those always have different color seals on each side, and there's not very many companies that use them. And there are some cases such as Campy freehubs where you remove one side's seal before installing it.

As I understand it, the seal (closure) type code you see on the seal of a bearing describes the type of sealing used by the closure it's inscribed on. I believe that in all cases, if it says the same thing on both sides, you don't have to worry about sidedness.